# A question about proving $\left|-a\right|=\left|a\right|$

Tags: proof-verification, absolute-value

I wonder if it is correct to prove this expression in this way.

$\left|a\right|=\sqrt{a^2}$

$\left|-a\right|=\sqrt{(-a)^2}$

$\sqrt{(-a)^2}=\sqrt{a^2}$

Comment: What definition of absolute value are you using? Is $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ your definition?

Comment: See [Absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties).

Comment: @5xum Yes, I'm trying to prove it by that property of absolute values.

Comment: Clearly you have just proven that it's true by using that definition but this has only proven it true for $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN usually the definition is that $|x| = x$ when $x\geq 0$ and $|x| = -x$ otherwise.

Comment: @PeterForeman thanks for verifying it. May I ask you a question. Why did you mention that it has only proven it true for $a\in R$?

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you for informing me about this definition but I don't get what should I understand by this definition. Sorry

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN That's not what I asked. I asked you what your **definition** of absolute value is.

Comment: The definition of absolute value is this; $\left|x\right| = \begin{cases} x, & x\geq0 \\ -x, & x\lt0 \end{cases}$

Comment: @Muhammed Because this is true for any $a\in\mathbb{C}$. In fact $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ we have that $|ab|=|a||b|$. Also $\sqrt{x^2}\ne|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @PeterForeman Oh, okay. I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but if you're **not** using the definition $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$ your proof relies on another "theorem", namely that $|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$. Since you're relying on an identity that has to be proven first it's not very elegant proof since you could as simply prove it directly from the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a variable $x\in\Bbb R$ we define $|x|=\begin{cases} x\iff x\ge 0\\ -x\iff x<0\end{cases}$

So you can see that $x\ge 0\implies |x|=x$ and $|-x|=x$ and in the sane way $x<0\implies |x|=-x$ and $|-x|=-x$